# C# Scoping or similar error? Expected number of coin tosses for a specified sequence to appear

Tags: c#

This program calculates the expected number of toin cosses until a given sequence will appear. The formula sums powers of two, where powers are those k for which the first k elements of the sequence match the last k elements, in order.

My question is why, when I test it with two different sequences, it only returns one result twice. I assume that it is doing exactly what it looks like and overwriting `test1` with `test4` when `test4` is instanciated, but this code looks to me to be similar to code from smaller exercises that did not have this overwriting behaviour.

This is my second programming course, and my first in C#, neither has been in my mother tongue, so I might be a bit slow with some of the concepts.
I suspect this has to do with one of the lines with `public static...` (I am not sure how to refer to them) or maybe a protection level. The expectation for `test1` should be 38 (2 + 2^2 + 2^5).

```
using System;
namespace CSProject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Expectation tests");
            PlayerSequence test1 = new PlayerSequence("bc00100");
            PlayerSequence test4 = new PlayerSequence("101101");

            Console.WriteLine("Expectation of test1 bc00100");
            Console.WriteLine (test1.Expectation ());
            Console.WriteLine("Expectation of test4 101101");
            Console.WriteLine(test4.Expectation());
        }
    }

    class PlayerSequence
    {
        //ATTRIBUTES
        private static bool[] sequence;

        //CONSTRUCTORS
        public PlayerSequence()
        {
        }

        public PlayerSequence(string sequence_String)//Seems to work!!
            {
                char[] sequence_array = sequence_String.ToCharArray();
                int inputLength = sequence_array.Length;
                int sequence_length = 0;
                for( int i = 0; i < inputLength; i++) {
                    if (sequence_array[i] == '1' || sequence_array[i] == '0') {
                        sequence_length++;
                    }
                }
                sequence = new bool[sequence_length];///KEYItem
                int input_index_adjustment = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < inputLength; i++) {
                    int sVal;
                    if (!Int32.TryParse(sequence_String[i].ToString(), out sVal))
                    {
                        input_index_adjustment++;
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (sVal == (Int32)1)
                        PlayerSequence.sequence[i - input_index_adjustment] = true;
                    if (sVal == (Int32)0)
                        PlayerSequence.sequence[i - input_index_adjustment] = false;
                    if(sVal != 1 && sVal != 0)
                        input_index_adjustment++;
                }
            }

        public override string ToString()//Works
        {
            string retString;
            retString = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < sequence.Length;i++) {
                if (sequence[i] == true) retString = retString + "T ";
                else retString = retString + "H ";
            }
            return retString;
        }

        public ulong Expectation(){
            ulong espTA = 0;
            for (int kexp = 0; kexp < /*PlayerSequence.*/sequence.Length; kesp++)
            {
                if(SeqCheck(sequence,kesp+1))
                    expTA = expTA + (ulong)Math.Pow(2, kexp+1);
            }
            return espTA;
        }//end Expectation

        public static bool SeqCheck(bool[] toCheck, int k){
            //Test of required property for each power of 2 here k
            int a = toCheck.Length ;
            bool seqgood = false;
            bool[] checkStart = new bool[k];
            bool[] checkEnd = new bool[k];
            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {//loop sets up subarrays to compare
                checkStart[i] = toCheck[i];
                checkEnd[i] = toCheck[a - k + i];
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++){//loop does comparison
                if(checkStart[i] != checkEnd[i])
                {
                    seqgood = false;
                    break;
                }
                seqgood = true;
            }
            return seqgood;
        }//end SeqCheck   
    }//end PlayerSequence class
}//End this section of the namespace
```

Comment: Use step through debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is your use of the static keyword for the local variable in your class.  By doin so, you make the variable a part of the type (PlayerSequence) and not the instance of PlayerSequence (test1, test4).  Below worked on my machine.

```
class PlayerSequence
{
    //ATTRIBUTES
    private bool[] sequence;

    //CONSTRUCTORS
    public PlayerSequence()
    {
    }

    public PlayerSequence(string sequence_String)//Seems to work!!
    {
        char[] sequence_array = sequence_String.ToCharArray();
        int inputLength = sequence_array.Length;
        int sequence_length = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < inputLength; i++)
        {
            if (sequence_array[i] == '1' || sequence_array[i] == '0')
            {
                sequence_length++;
            }
        }
        sequence = new bool[sequence_length];///KEYItem
        int input_index_adjustment = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < inputLength; i++)
        {
            int sVal;
            if (!Int32.TryParse(sequence_String[i].ToString(), out sVal))
            {
                input_index_adjustment++;
                continue;
            }
            if (sVal == (Int32)1)
                sequence[i - input_index_adjustment] = true;
            if (sVal == (Int32)0)
                sequence[i - input_index_adjustment] = false;
            if (sVal != 1 && sVal != 0)
                input_index_adjustment++;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()//Works
    {
        string retString;
        retString = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < sequence.Length; i++)
        {
            if (sequence[i] == true) retString = retString + "T ";
            else retString = retString + "H ";
        }
        return retString;
    }

    public ulong Expectation()
    {
        ulong espTA = 0;
        for (int kexp = 0; kexp < sequence.Length; kexp++)
        {
            if (SeqCheck(sequence, kexp + 1))
                espTA = espTA + (ulong)Math.Pow(2, kexp + 1);
        }
        return espTA;
    }//end Expectation

    public bool SeqCheck(bool[] toCheck, int k)
    {
        //Test of required property for each power of 2 here k
        int a = toCheck.Length;
        bool seqgood = false;
        bool[] checkStart = new bool[k];
        bool[] checkEnd = new bool[k];
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        {//loop sets up subarrays to compare
            checkStart[i] = toCheck[i];
            checkEnd[i] = toCheck[a - k + i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        {//loop does comparison
            if (checkStart[i] != checkEnd[i])
            {
                seqgood = false;
                break;
            }
            seqgood = true;
        }
        return seqgood;
    }//end SeqCheck   
}
```